# How to use thirdweb contracts with node v14 in reactjs?

Tags: solidity, javascript, ethereumjs, react, web3-providers

Hey everyone I am using useStorageUpload  from @thirdweb-dev/storage for uploading NFT image and metadata to ipfs but it is giving me errors which I cannot figure out where am I doing wrong

Here's my code-

```
import { useStorageUpload } from "@thirdweb-dev/storage";

const { mutateAsync: upload } = useStorageUpload();

    const addNft = async () => {
        const name = artCollectionss_name;
        const price = artCollectionss_price;
        const description = artCollectionss_short_desc;

        if (!name || !description || !price || !collectionsImg) {
            return;
        }
        const data = JSON.stringify({
            name, description, image: collectionsImg
        });

        const uri = await upload({ data: data });
        console.log(uri);
}
```

here is the error:-

```
./node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/storage/dist/thirdweb-dev-storage.esm.js 384:40
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (384:40)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|   constructor(options) {
|     _defineProperty(this, "uploadWithGatewayUrl", void 0);
>     this.uploadWithGatewayUrl = options?.uploadWithGatewayUrl || false;
|   }
|   async uploadBatch(data, options) {
```

After checking the error I found that my project is using node version 14 and this supports version 18.

**So can anyone tell me how can I use thirdweb sdk with node v14 in ReactJS?**
Also I need to know do I need api key to use the thirdweb sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to the problem that I found is importing **useStorageUpload** from **@thirdweb-dev/react** instead of **@thirdweb-dev/storage**

Here's the updated code-

```
import { useStorageUpload } from "@thirdweb-dev/react";
```